# MVC3: Dispalying user name at front end, but controller must work user id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I hope i'm not bithering with my many questions...

i'm creating users in the ASPNETDB.MDF database with the asp.net configuration.

i have a client MVC, and i want when a client is created, edited, or deleted, it must dispaly the user_name and last_user_name  of the user that performed the action. These two properties r in the client model. i want my controller to only deal with the ID(PK) of the users, and not their names. I only know how to make the controller work with the user names. How do i ensure that any functionality is done with the id but the display is the user_name? Here is my create method in my clientcontroller

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new title
        {

            create_dt = DateTime.Now,
            last_maint_dt = DateTime.Now,
            row_version = 1,
            status = "ACTIVE",
            user_id = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name,
            last_user_id = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the default ASP.NET Membership Provider you can find the user GUID for an account by accessing `System.Web.Security.Membership`. Then you can use the GetUser() method and pass it the username as an argument.

```
//Get Current User ID
var user = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);

if (user != null)
{
    string id = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
}
```

And if you have the GUID and want the Username

```
var user = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(id);
if (user != null)
{
    string username = user.UserName;
}
```

Comment: ok...so how do assign that to my username and last username propeties in my sql server database, which are string variables?

Comment: Are you asking how to save a User to the database? I'm not quite sure if I understand your question.

Comment: in the above code, user_id and last_user_id are string properties in the client model. So How do i make my controller work with the id of the user in the ASPNETDB, but when a user creates a client, the view displays the user name of the user creating the client? More of how do i transform the view to display the username,when the controller is working with the unique Identifier(ID) of that user?

Comment: Oh, well there are lots of options to do that. You could add two new properties username and last username and simply display them in View. Or you could use inline C# code in the view to pull the username for the unique ID. Adding additional properties would probably be the best.